# geforce and quadro card together?

Tags: nvidia-geforce, nvidia-quadro

I have seen this before but unfortunately the answers are never specific enough. I have always used a quadro card for the quad buffer feature. My new machine has a geforce titan card, because I wanted to take advantage of all it's power. I was quite embarrassed to realize after years of enjoying a quadro that the geforce has no quad buffer capabilities, and did not realize it lacked this ability... which I miss tremendously [although the titan still has immense power].

I still have my quadro card and want to add it to my machine. I ONLY want it for the quad buffer ability and still want the geforce titan card to do the real work.

If I put them both in the machine, can this work? I have heard that if one has both then the quadro's capabilities can be 'unlocked' but will the machine be using the quadro or the geforce, and can this be set at all in any way if it wants to ignore the geforece and use the quadro card? 
I find it confusing to know just which card will be the one being used, I really only want the geforce card being used but I just want the quad buffer feature there from the quadro.

So IS this possible, and if so HOW? I keep hearing yes, you can do this just add each driver for each card- but HOW do you even do that? Or do you just add the quadro driver?
but if you do that then won't it ignore the geforce card?
It is terribly confusing, please does anybody know?
thanks very much,

Comment: Have you tried to just install the driver?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: Yes you can run both cards.
Now for your specific problem.
I am asuming you want the quadro to do the rendering when you work and when you play you would like to use the geforce to paly.
Do you run multiple monitors? If so it would be an easy yes due to running the cards separately.
 I wouldn't know how to run both cards on 1 monitor though other than switching the dvi/vga cable from one to the other. Unless nVidia's control panel lets you switch which card is the main card( I know when it comes to PhysX you can tell it which card)

Comment: Or connect both graphics cards to different ports on the monitor. (assuming The monitor has multiple ports).